# Executing a collection of futures sequentially

Tags: rust, future

I have a collection of futures which I want to combine into a single future that gets them executed sequentially.

I looked into the [`futures_ordered`](https://docs.rs/futures/0.1.17/futures/stream/fn.futures_ordered.html) function. It seems to return the results sequentially but the futures get executed concurrently.

I tried to [`fold`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.fold) the futures, combining them with [`and_then`](https://docs.rs/futures/0.1.17/futures/future/trait.Future.html#method.and_then). However, that is tricky with the type system.

```
let tasks = vec![ok(()), ok(()), ok(())];

let combined_task = tasks.into_iter().fold(
    ok(()),                             // seed
    |acc, task| acc.and_then(|_| task), // accumulator
);
```

[playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=478ee33aff8aa5accd30803e1ddb0672&version=stable)

This gives the following error:

```
error[E0308]: mismatched types
  --> src/main.rs:10:21
   |
10 |         |acc, task| acc.and_then(|_| task), // accumulator
   |                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ expected struct `futures::FutureResult`, found struct `futures::AndThen`
   |
   = note: expected type `futures::FutureResult<_, _>`
              found type `futures::AndThen<futures::FutureResult<_, _>, futures::FutureResult<(), _>, [closure@src/main.rs:10:34: 10:42 task:_]>`
```

I'm probably approaching this wrong but I've run out of ideas.

Comment: Posting as a comment rather than an answer as I don't know how to fix it off the top of my head: since you provide `ok(())` - which returns a `FutureResult` - as the initial value, `fold` expects you to return a `FutureResult` from each iteration of the closure. In other words, the inferred types are too specific.

Comment: *a single future that gets them executed sequentially* — why would you want to do such a thing? Since your futures don't depend on each other, there's no obvious reason to introduce forced serialization.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Combine [`iter_ok`](https://docs.rs/futures/0.1.17/futures/stream/fn.iter_ok.html) and [`Stream::for_each`](https://docs.rs/futures/0.1.17/futures/stream/trait.Stream.html#method.for_each):

```
use futures::Stream;
use futures::future::ok;
use futures::stream::iter_ok;

let tasks = vec![ok(()), ok(()), ok(())];

let combined_task = iter_ok::<_, ()>(tasks).for_each(|f| f);
```

`iter_ok` produces a stream of the passed items, and never throws an error (that is why you sometimes need to fix the error type).  The closure passed to `for_each` then returns a `Future` to be run for each item - here simply the items that were passed in.

`for_each` then drives each returned future to completion before moving to the next one, like you wanted.  It will also abort with the first error it encounters, and requires the inner futures to return `()` on success.

`for_each` itself returns a `Future` that will either fail (like described above) or return `()` on completion.

```
test tests::bench_variant_buffered ... bench:      22,356 ns/iter (+/- 1,816)
test tests::bench_variant_boxed ...    bench:       8,575 ns/iter (+/- 1,042)
test tests::bench_variant_for_each ... bench:       4,070 ns/iter (+/- 531)
```

Comment: This should be accepted instead of my answer, I completely missed that the asker actually wanted a `Future` at the end. I wrote my answer based upon the OP wanting a `Stream`.

Comment: Accepted @Stefan's answer for the most optimal solution in my scenario. Also big thanks to Lukazoid and Shepmaster - I learned a lot of about the futures crate.

Answer (score 6):

`Stream` has a function [`buffered`](https://docs.rs/futures/0.1.17/futures/stream/trait.Stream.html#method.buffered) which allows you to limit how many futures are polled concurrently.

If you have a collection of futures, you can create a stream and use `buffered` like so:

```
let tasks = vec![future1, future2];
let stream = ::futures::stream::iter_ok(tasks);
let mut when_result_ready = stream.buffered(1);
```

`when_result_ready` will now be a `Stream` implementation which only polls one future at a time and moves to the next once each future completes.

**Update**

Based on comments and profiling it appears `buffered` has a large overhead so another solution is to convert each `Future` to a `Stream` and [`flatten`](https://docs.rs/futures/0.1.17/futures/stream/trait.Stream.html#method.flatten) them:

```
iter_ok(tasks).map(|f|f.into_stream()).flatten()
```

`flatten` states that "each individual stream will get exhausted before moving on to the next." meaning no `Future` will be polled before the previous one is completed. In my local profiling this seems to be ~80% faster than the `buffered` approach.

---

Both of my answers above result in a `Stream` of results where each source `Future` is polled sequentially and the results returned. What the asker actually asked for was just a single `Future` at the end and not the results of each source `Future`, if this is the case, the answer from Stefan may be more useful and prove to have better performance.

Comment: Thanks! I especially like the granularity of being able to specify level of concurrency through buffer size.

Comment: I think `buffered` has a high overhead (there should be some `Arc` objects in the middle passed to `with_notify` every time an inner future is polled).  Boxing might be cheaper than `buffered(1)`.

Comment: @Stefan I did a quick bench and the boxed variant is roughly 30% faster than the buffer solution with a lot low lower std deviation. Although I'm not confident that any of the crucial parts weren't stripped away by optimizations. https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=d5dc4ef2eb5f0611848edc9f3829fa40&version=nightly

Comment: Actually, `and_then(|f| f)` ([`Stream::and_then`](https://docs.rs/futures/0.1.17/futures/stream/trait.Stream.html#method.and_then)) should be "the same" as `buffered(1)`, just a lot faster.

Answer (score 2):

As [mentioned in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48081740/executing-a-collection-of-futures-sequentially#comment83138171_48081740), your types are too concrete.

You can envision the implementation of `fold` as doing something like this:

```
let (task0, task1, task2) = (ok(()), ok(()), ok(()));

let mut combined_task = ok(()); // seed
combined_task = combined_task.and_then(|_| task0); 
combined_task = combined_task.and_then(|_| task1); 
combined_task = combined_task.and_then(|_| task2);
```

The variable `combined_task` needs to be updated in place with a new value *of the same type*. Since we start with `ok(())`, that's the type each step needs to return. However, the return type of `and_then` is different; it's an `AndThen`. In fact, `AndThen` is a generic type containing the closure and the underlying future, so each step will produce a distinct type with potentially a different size:

1. `FutureResult<()>`
2. `AndThen<FutureResult<()>, closure0>`
3. `AndThen<AndThen<FutureResult<()>, closure0>, closure1>`
4. `AndThen<AndThen<AndThen<FutureResult<()>, closure0>, closure1>, closure2>`

Instead, you can create a unified type by producing a *boxed trait object* at each step:

```
let (task0, task1, task2) = (ok(()), ok(()), ok(()));

let mut combined_task: Box<Future<Item = (), Error = ()>> = Box::new(ok(())); // seed
combined_task = Box::new(combined_task.and_then(|_| task0)); 
combined_task = Box::new(combined_task.and_then(|_| task1)); 
combined_task = Box::new(combined_task.and_then(|_| task2));
```

1. `Box<Future<Item = (), Error = ()>>`
2. `Box<Future<Item = (), Error = ()>>`
3. `Box<Future<Item = (), Error = ()>>`
4. `Box<Future<Item = (), Error = ()>>`

Converting back to the `fold` syntax:

```
let combined_task: Box<Future<Item = (), Error = ()>> =
    tasks.into_iter().fold(Box::new(ok(())), |acc, task| {
        Box::new(acc.and_then(|_| task))
    });
```

See also:

- [Creating Diesel.rs queries with a dynamic number of .and()'s](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48696290/155423)

Comment: Thanks! I was thinking of this but prefer to avoid heap allocations / runtime dispatch if possible. Although I'm not sure how the other buffered stream approach is internally implemented.

Comment: Hi, @Shepmaster , can you please explain more about why do add `Box` can fix this issue? I occurred same problem, if I specify function returns `impl Future<Item=String, Error=Error>`, program compiles failed with `expect futures::FutureResult, found futures::AndThen`, but when I changed return type to `Box<Future<Item=String, Error=Error>>`, everything can be compiled.

Comment: @Songday I have a much longer explanation in another answer (now linked from this answer). Can you check that and see if it explains it adequately? If not, let me know what's missing and I'll try to update.

Comment: Thank you @Shepmaster , I read your post several times but can't understand completely. The `Box`, my understanding is, everything which is unsized, needs `Box` wrapper. In my case, function returns `impl Future` trait that was unsized, so Rust refuses to compile, right? I still feeling I was misunderstanding something....

Comment: @Songday not quite; unsized types don't really play into it here. The problem is that each step has a different type (which can have different sizes). `impl Future` is *not* unsized. The compiler knows the concrete type and size, although the programmer does not.

Answer (score 2):

In my case (stable `async/await`) this code was very helpful:

```rust
use futures::{stream, StreamExt};

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() -> Result<(), Box<dyn std::error::Error + 'static>> {
    let data = vec![1,2,3];

    stream::iter(data).for_each(|id| async move {
        let request = async { id }; // async io request
        let res = request.await;
        println!("res: {:?}", res);
        ()
    }).await;
    
    Ok(())
}
```

https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=ad5feaf0cbb3597730c22df2eaf4a606

Answer (score 1):

When I needed something like this (mainly because I was debugging an issue) I ended up writing a `seq` combinator composing `loop_fn` [like so](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=faf1d276184f904e112f5da57c5fdfe1&version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2015):

```
fn seq<I>(
    i: I,
) -> impl Future<Item = Vec<<I::Item as IntoFuture>::Item>, Error = <I::Item as IntoFuture>::Error>
where
    I: IntoIterator,
    I::Item: IntoFuture,
{
    let iter = i.into_iter();
    loop_fn((vec![], iter), |(mut output, mut iter)| {
        let fut = if let Some(next) = iter.next() {
            Either::A(next.into_future().map(|v| Some(v)))
        } else {
            Either::B(future::ok(None))
        };

        fut.and_then(move |val| {
            if let Some(val) = val {
                output.push(val);
                Ok(Loop::Continue((output, iter)))
            } else {
                Ok(Loop::Break(output))
            }
        })
    })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just iterate a vector using `await` inside `for`

```
use std::future;

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() {

    let futures = vec![future::ready(1), future::ready(2), future::ready(3)];

    let mut result = vec![];

    for future in futures {
        result.push(future.await);
    }

    dbg!(result);
    // output
    //[src/bin/future.rs:14] result = [
    // 1,
    // 2,
    // 3,
    //]

}
```