# Creating Diesel.rs queries with a dynamic number of .and()'s

Tags: rust, rust-diesel

While playing with Diesel, I got stuck writing a function which takes an vector of `String`s as input and does the following:

1. Combine all `String`s to a large query
2. run the query on the `Connection`
3. process the result
4. return a `Vec`

If I construct the query in one step, it works just fine:

```
fn get_books(authors: Vec<String>, connection: SqliteConnection) {
    use schema::ebook::dsl::*;

    let inner = author
        .like(format!("%{}%", authors[0]))
        .and(author.like(format!("%{}%", authors[1])))
        .and(author.like(format!("%{}%", authors[2])));

    ebook
        .filter(inner)
        .load::<Ebook>(&connection)
        .expect("Error loading ebook");
}
```

If I try to generate the query in more steps (needed in order to work with  the variable length of the input vector) I can't get it to compile:

```
fn get_books(authors: Vec<String>, connection: SqliteConnection) {
    use schema::ebook::dsl::*;

    let mut inner = author
        .like(format!("%{}%", authors[0]))
        .and(author.like(format!("%{}%", authors[1]))); // <1>

    inner = inner.and(author.like(format!("%{}%", authors[2]))); // <2>

    ebook
        .filter(inner)
        .load::<Ebook>(&connection)
        .expect("Error loading ebook");
}
```

This generates the following error:

```
inner = inner.and(author.like(format!("%{}%",authors[2])));
        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ expected struct `diesel::expression::operators::Like`, found struct `diesel::expression::operators::And`
```

I don't understand why Rust expects a `Like` and not an `And`. The function an the line line marked `<1>` returns an `And` and therefore an `And` is stored in `inner`.

What am I missing? Why does the first bit of code compile and the second won't? What is the right way to generate this kind of query?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The first thing you need to do is look at the **complete** error message:

```
error[E0308]: mismatched types
  --> src/main.rs:23:13
   |
23 |     inner = inner.and(author.like(format!("%{}%", authors[2])));//<2>
   |             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ expected struct `diesel::expression::operators::Like`, found struct `diesel::expression::operators::And`
   |
   = note: expected type `diesel::expression::operators::And<diesel::expression::operators::Like<_, _>, _>`
              found type `diesel::expression::operators::And<diesel::expression::operators::And<diesel::expression::operators::Like<_, _>, diesel::expression::operators::Like<schema::ebook::columns::author, diesel::expression::bound::Bound<diesel::sql_types::Text, std::string::String>>>, _>`
```

It's long, but that's because it's fully qualified. Lets shorten the last part a bit:

```
expected type `And<Like<_, _>, _>`
   found type `And<And<Like<_, _>, Like<author, Bound<Text, String>>>, _>`
```

If you review the documentation for [`and`](http://docs.diesel.rs/diesel/expression_methods/trait.BoolExpressionMethods.html#method.and), you'll see that every call to `and` consumes the receiver and returns a brand new type — `And`:

```
fn and<T: AsExpression<Bool>>(self, other: T) -> And<Self, T::Expression>
```

This is the core of Diesel's ability to generate strongly-typed SQL expressions with no run-time overhead. All of the work is delegated to the type system. In fact, the creator of Diesel has [an entire talk where he shows how far Diesel pushes the type system and what benefits it has](https://confreaks.tv/videos/rustconf2017-type-system-tips-for-the-real-world).

Turning back to your question, it's impossible to store an `And<_, _>` in the same location as an `And<And<_, _>, _>` because they will have different sizes and are in fact different types. At the root, this is the same as trying to store an integer in a boolean.

In fact, there's **no** way to know what concrete type you need because you *don't even know how many conditions* you will have — it depends on the size of the vector.

In this case, we have to give up static dispatch and move to dynamic dispatch via a *trait object*. Diesel has a specific trait for this case (which also has good examples): [`BoxableExpression`](https://docs.diesel.rs/2.0.x/diesel/expression/trait.BoxableExpression.html).

The remaining piece is to convert your authors to `like` expressions and combine them. We need a base case, however, for when `authors` is empty. We construct a trivially true statement (`author = author`) for that.

```
#[macro_use]
extern crate diesel;

use diesel::SqliteConnection;
use diesel::prelude::*;
use diesel::sql_types::Bool;

mod schema {
    table! {
        ebook (id) {
            id -> Int4,
            author -> Text,
        }
    }
}

fn get_books(authors: Vec<String>, connection: SqliteConnection) {
    use schema::ebook::dsl::*;

    let always_true = Box::new(author.eq(author));
    let query: Box<BoxableExpression<schema::ebook::table, _, SqlType = Bool>> = authors
        .into_iter()
        .map(|name| author.like(format!("%{}%", name)))
        .fold(always_true, |query, item| {
            Box::new(query.and(item))
        });

    ebook
        .filter(query)
        .load::<(i32, String)>(&connection)
        .expect("Error loading ebook");
}

fn main() {}
```

---

I also wouldn't be surprised if there wasn't a better *SQL* way of doing this. It appears that PostgreSQL has the `WHERE col LIKE ANY( subselect )` and `WHERE col LIKE ALL( subselect )` forms, for example.