# How to execute a collection of statements in Tiberius?

Tags: sql-server, database, rust

I could not figure out how to iterate over a collection and execute statements one by one with Tiberius.

My current code looks like this (simplified):

```rust
use futures::Future;
use futures_state_stream::StateStream;
use tokio::executor::current_thread;
use tiberius::SqlConnection;

fn find_files(files: &mut Vec<String>) {
    files.push(String::from("file1.txt"));
    files.push(String::from("file2.txt"));
    files.push(String::from("file3.txt"));
}

fn main() {
    let mut files: Vec<String> = Vec::new();
    find_files(&mut files);

    let future = SqlConnection::connect(CONN_STR)
        .and_then(|conn| {
            conn.simple_exec("CREATE TABLE db.dbo.[Filenames] ( [Spalte 0] varchar(80) );")
        })
        .and_then(|(_, conn)| {
            for k in files.iter() {
                let sql = format!("INSERT INTO db.dbo.Filenames ([Spalte 0]) VALUES ('{}')", k);
                &conn.simple_exec(sql);
            }
            Ok(())
        });

    current_thread::block_on_all(future).unwrap();
}
```

I got the following error message

```
error[E0382]: use of moved value: `conn`
  --> src/main.rs:23:18
   |
20 |         .and_then(|(_, conn)| {
   |                        ---- move occurs because `conn` has type `tiberius::SqlConnection<std::boxed::Box<dyn tiberius::BoxableIo>>`, which does not implement the `Copy` trait
...
23 |                 &conn.simple_exec(sql);
   |                  ^^^^ value moved here, in previous iteration of loop
```

I'm new to Rust but I know there is something wrong with the use of the `conn` variable but nothing works.

Answer (score 0):

There are actual two questions here:

1. The header question: how to perform multiple sequential statements using tiberius?
2. The specific question concerning why an error message comes from a specific bit of code.
   I will answer them separately.

Multiple statements

There are many ways to skin a cat.  In TDS (the underlying protocol Tiberius is implementing) there is the possibility to execute several statements in a single command.  They just need to be delimited by using semicolon. The response from such an execution is in Tiberius represented a stream of futures, one for each statement.
So if your chain of statements is not too big to fit into one command, just build one string and send it over:

```
fn main() { 
    let mut files: Vec<String> = Vec::new(); 
    find_files(&mut files); 
    let stmts = vec![ 
        String::from( 
            "CREATE TABLE db.dbo.[Filenames] ( [Spalte 0] varchar(80) )")] 
        .into_iter() 
        .chain(files.iter().map(|k| 
            format!("INSERT INTO db.dbo.Filenames ([Spalte 0]) VALUES ('{}')", k))) 
        .collect::<Vec<_>>() 
        .join(";"); 

    let future 
        = SqlConnection::connect(std::env::var("CONN_STR").unwrap().as_str()) 
            .and_then(|conn| 
                conn.simple_exec(stmts) 
                    .into_stream() 
                    .and_then(|future| future) 
                    .for_each(|_| Ok(()))); 

    current_thread::block_on_all(future).unwrap(); 
}
```

There is some simple boilerplate in that example.

- `simple_exec` returns an `ExecResult`, a wrapper around the individual statement's future results.  Calling `into_stream() on that provides a stream of those futures.
- That stream of results need to be forced to be carried out, one way of doing that is to call `and_then`, which awaits each future and does something with it.
- We don't actually care about the results here, so we just do a noop `for_each`.

But, say that there is a *lot* of statements, more than can fit in a single TDS command, then there is a need to issue them separately (another case is when the statements themselves depend on earlier ones).  A version of that problem is solved in [How do I iterate over a Vec of functions returning Futures in Rust?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50850309/how-do-i-iterate-over-a-vec-of-functions-returning-futures-in-rust) .

Then finally, what is your specific error?  Well `conn` is *consumed* by `simple_exec`, so it cannot be used afterwards, that is what the error tells you.  If you want to use the connection after that execution is done you *have* to use the `Future` it returns, which is wrapping the mutated connection.  I defer to the link above, on one way to do that.