# How can I iteratively call Sha256::digest, passing the previous result to each subsequent call?

Tags: rust

I'm trying to implement iterated SHA256. This works:

```
use sha2::{Digest, Sha256}; // 0.8.2

fn main() {
    let preimage = [42; 80];
    let hash = Sha256::digest(&Sha256::digest(&preimage));
}
```

This doesn't:

```
use sha2::{Digest, Sha256}; // 0.8.2

fn main() {
    let preimage = [42; 80];
    let mut hash = preimage;
    for _ in 0..2 {
        hash = Sha256::digest(&hash);
    }
}
```

I get an error:

```
error[E0308]: mismatched types
 --> src/main.rs:7:16
  |
7 |         hash = Sha256::digest(&hash);
  |                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ expected array `[u8; 80]`, found struct `generic_array::GenericArray`
  |
  = note: expected array `[u8; 80]`
            found struct `generic_array::GenericArray<u8, typenum::uint::UInt<typenum::uint::UInt<typenum::uint::UInt<typenum::uint::UInt<typenum::uint::UInt<typenum::uint::UInt<typenum::uint::UTerm, typenum::bit::B1>, typenum::bit::B0>, typenum::bit::B0>, typenum::bit::B0>, typenum::bit::B0>, typenum::bit::B0>>`
```

I would like the second style so I can easily re-iterate more than twice.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As the compiler tells you, the types have to match to assign a new value to a variable. You can't store a `bool` where an `i32` should be. An array and a `GenericArray` are different types.

Your first attempt might be to make everything a `GenericArray`:

```
use sha2::{Digest, Sha256}; // 0.8.2
use generic_array_0_12_3::GenericArray; // 0.12.3

fn main() {
    let mut hash = GenericArray::clone_from_slice(&[42u8; 80]);
    for _ in 0..2 {
        hash = Sha256::digest(&hash);
    }
}
```

However, this will panic because your input array is 80 elements and the returned `GenericArray` must have 32 elements — that's the length of the SHA-256 digest!

Instead, you need to introduce some middle steps and a smidge of indirection:

```rust
use sha2::{Digest, Sha256}; // 0.8.2

fn main() {
    let input = [42u8; 80];
    let mut intermediate;
    let mut hash = &input[..];
    
    for _ in 0..2 {
        intermediate = Sha256::digest(&hash);
        hash = &intermediate[..];
    }
}
```

`input` is an array with 80 elements, `intermediate` is a `GenericArray<u8, 32>`, and `hash` is a `&[u8]`. Both `input` and `intermediate` can be viewed as a slice, so `hash` counts as a common type between the two.

See also:

- [Are polymorphic variables allowed?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28219519/155423)
- [Creating Diesel.rs queries with a dynamic number of .and()'s](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48696290/155423)

Comment: Works indeed (I only tried your second proposal) although I must admit I don't understand why.  What is the difference between this and my code? what happens under the hood there?

Comment: @Chipotle I think that it would make it more obvious if you write out the type of `hash` and what type is assigned to `hash` in each of the code examples.

Answer (score 4):

The probably easiest solution is to pull the first iteration out of the loop:

```
let preimage = [42; 80];
let mut hash = Sha256::digest(&preimage);
for _ in 1..2 {
    hash = Sha256::digest(&hash);
}
```

([Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=f6ffd7a0d83f5db6e3f13dad0859071f))

This makes `hash` a `GenericArray` right from the beginning, so the loop works just fine.

Comment: A benefit of this style is that you are guaranteed to hash at least once. The original question and other answer allow hashing zero times, which seems unlikely to be desired.