# Best practice for returning values from for loops in rust?

Tags: rust

I'm new to rust I'm finished reading chapter 1 of the purple crab book and I'm stuck.
I'm using this crate for sha1 https://docs.rs/sha-1/0.9.1/sha1/

I want to return the output of  m.finalize();
How do I achieve this in rust?

in python I'd do something like this

```py
def gen_chain():
    chain_redux = "some_Str"
    hash = None 
    hasher = Sha1()
    for i in range(0,iterations):
        hasher.update(chain_redux)
        hash = hasher.finalize() 
        hasher.reset()
        chain_redux = redux(hash)
        print(chain_redux)
    return hash
```

Heres what I have in rust

```
fn calc_chain(name_table:&Vec<String> ,iterations:i32) -> GenericArray<u8, <sha1::Sha1 as Digest>::OutputSize>{

    let mut m = sha1::Sha1::new();
    let mut chain_redux = &name_table[0];
    let mut hash;
    // The above doesnt fly in rust. and i can't figure out how to make the arr! macro return a 
    // GenericArray<u8, <sha1::Sha1 as Digest>::OutputSize> I also don't know if I should. 
    for i in 0..iterations {
        println!("Curr string: {}",chain_redux);
        m.update(chain_redux);
        hash = m.finalize(); // let hash = m.finalize() here keeps me from returning it because rust 
                             // deletes it after the for loop scope
        m.reset();
        chain_redux = redux(&hash, name_table);
        println!("Redux Output: {}",chain_redux);
    };
    hash 

}
```

Any rust tips/pointers would be appreciated here also.

Comment: Related: [How can I iteratively call Sha256::digest, passing the previous result to each subsequent call?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62678226)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of Rustacean principles is to use iterators as much as possible as they're frequently faster than plain `for` loops and the standard library has quite many fancy functions to solve anything with iterators.

Unfortunately the approach with iterators **is not ideal here**. Firstly, because it doesn't look fancy and we have to use ugly `.last().unwrap()` to get the last hash. Secondly, the `map()` iterator there has side-effects (it changes `m` and `chain_redux`) which is not so idiomatic for iterators, yet doing it idiomatically would require a few more lines for `fold()` iterator

```
fn calc_chain(name_table: &Vec<String>, iterations:i32) -> GenericArray<u8, <sha1::Sha1 as Digest>::OutputSize> {
    let mut m = sha1::Sha1::new();
    let mut chain_redux = &name_table[0];
    (0..iterations)
        .map(|_| { 
            m.update(chain_redux);
            let hash = m.finalize_reset()
            chain_redux = redux(&hash, name_table);
            hash 
        })
        .last()
        .unwrap()
}
```

If you're yet unfamiliar with iterators you can read it as follows:

1. `0..iterations` is the same iterator you used in your `for` loop, it will give you numbers `0, 1, 2, ..`  up to `iterations-1` if you *ask* it to do so
2. `.map(|_| { ... })` is an iterator which when you *ask* it for a value, it will take a value from previous iterator (i.e. numbers from `0..iterations`) and will return another value based on given function. There, for each iteration a corresponding hash will be returned
3. `.last()` is the function that finally starts to *ask* previous iterator to give values, and as soon as the previous iterator has no more values to give on demand it will return the last value (i.e. the last hash)
4. `.unwrap()` is needed because `.last()` actually returns an `Option`, but we believe that there was atleast one computed hash, so we just unwrap it

Answer (score 2):

I think the problem here is that in the Python code, you have a special value you return if the loop executes zero times (because `iterations = 0`) - you return `None`. In Python, any variable can be `None` so this is fine.

In Rust, there is no `None` value by default for variables - a variable of type `GenericArray` can't be `None`, so you need to be more explicit and use a type which *can* be `None`, such as an `Option` (which is a type which can be `None` or `Some`). Something like:

```rust
fn calc_chain(name_table:&Vec<String> ,iterations:i32) -> Option<GenericArray<u8, <sha1::Sha1 as Digest>::OutputSize>> {
    let mut m = sha1::Sha1::new();
    let mut chain_redux = &name_table[0];
    let mut maybe_hash = None;
    for i in 0..iterations {
        println!("Curr string: {}",chain_redux);
        m.update(chain_redux);
        let this_iteration_hash = m.finalize()
        m.reset();
        chain_redux = redux(&this_iteration_hash, name_table);
        println!("Redux Output: {}",chain_redux);
        maybe_hash = Some(this_iteration_hash)
    };
    maybe_hash 
}
```

If you have a default value you'd like to return instead of an `Option` you could change the line which just reads `maybe_hash` to instead use [`unwrap_or`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/option/enum.Option.html#method.unwrap_or) or [`unwrap_or_else`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/option/enum.Option.html#method.unwrap_or_else):

```rust
maybe_hash.unwrap_or_else(make_default_array)
```

Alternatively, if you know that `iterations` is always greater than 0, you could return a `GenericArray` by changing the `maybe_hash` line to:

```rust
maybe_hash.unwrap()
```

which is asserting that `maybe_hash` is not `None`, but if someone *does* call your function with `iterations = 0`, the program will panic.

Answer (score -1):

You can do it this way:

```
// Use NonZeroU32 because we always run one iteration
fn calc_chain(name_table:&Vec<String> ,iterations:NonZeroU32) -> GenericArray<u8, <sha1::Sha1 as Digest>::OutputSize>{
    let mut m = sha1::Sha1::new();
    let mut chain_redux = &name_table[0];
    let mut hash = {
        // Run first iteration
        println!("Curr string: {}",chain_redux);
        m.update(chain_redux);
        let hash = m.finalize();
        m.reset();
        chain_redux = redux(&hash, name_table);
        println!("Redux Output: {}",chain_redux);
        hash // Scope returns first value
    };
    for i in 1..iterations.get() {
        println!("Curr string: {}",chain_redux);
        m.update(chain_redux);
        hash = m.finalize();
        m.reset();
        chain_redux = redux(&hash, name_table);
        println!("Redux Output: {}",chain_redux);
    };
    hash 
}
```